# Postconcussion symptoms: how long? Are they reversible? Treatment options?

Tags: brain, headache, memory, dizziness

I had an accident 7 days ago and I have been suffering from short term memory loss for about a week now. I can't remember anything from the accident or the day before it. Also, I suffer from headaches and dizziness.

**How long do these postconcussion symptoms last and are they reversible? Also are there any treatments for it?**

Comment: Hi @M.G. Welcome to Health SE. Unfortunately we don't provide individualized diagnosis or personalized management plan on this site. Though I think your question could be interesting to other people who suffer from similar symptoms after a TBI so I have edited your question by deleting the most personal parts and made it more general. Hope you understand. Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

**Postconcussion syndrome** is common following a traumatic brain injury (independent on the severity of the TBI). According to some studies, **30%-80% of patients with mild to moderate brain injury will suffer from some symptoms of postconcussion syndrome (PCS)**.

The symptoms, severity, risk factors and timing vary greatly between individuals.

**Risk factors of PCS:**

- **female and older age are at increased risk** of developing PCS
- brain injuries following a **motor vehicle accident, fall or assault are at higher risk** of leading to PCS compared to brain injuries following sport trauma
- **individual susceptibility (psychological, premorbid dispositions)** are associated with increased risk of developing PCS

**Symptoms of PCS:**
The most frequently reported symptoms in patients with PCS are **headaches, vertigo (dizziness), fatigue, psychological impairments** (irritability, anxiety, insomnia, loss of concentration and memory, and noise sensitivity)

**Treatment of PCS:**
The current recommended approach for PCS treatment is mainly **symptomatic** and should be tailored to the patient needs. There is no "gold standard" treatment for all PCS patients.

**Prognosis of PCS:** Several studies have investigated the short and long term outcome of PCS. Most of the patients report an **improvement of symptoms and disability within the first 7 to 10 days while after one to three months, the vast majority of patients report complete resolution of symptoms.**

*Sources:* Evan RW. Postconcussion syndrome. UpToDate. Sept 2016. https://www.uptodate.com/contents/postconcussion-syndrome?source=search_result&search=post%20concussion&selectedTitle=1~12